# google spreadsheet like platform which will allow only to edit particular cells to non admins

Tags: spreadsheet

I'm looking for some kind of google spreadsheets like platform which will allow participants to edit only specified cells. As an administrator I should be able also to view date and time when the cell was edited.

Answer (score 1):

**[Grist](https://www.getgrist.com/)** is a open source spreadsheet with [access rules](https://support.getgrist.com/access-rules/) (an experimental feature - BETA). You can try it on the cloud for free if you create an account. *By generating an API key, you will be able to make API calls for your own account.*

From GiHub :

> [This repository is in a pre-release state.](https://github.com/gristlabs/grist-core/) Its
> release will be announced when it has all the planned components, and
> a solid independent build and test set-up. Currently, stand-alone
> server functionality is present, along with a single-user web client.

Access rules

- Restrict access to columns
- Row-level access control
- Document history

  - Activity
  - Snapshots

[image: Table Rules]
[image]